# How to send a text message from Skype on Android?

Tags: sms, skype

So, I just spent 30 minutes trying to find out where to send a text message (SMS) to a phone number using the latest version of Skype on Android.

[image]

Does anyone know if it's still possible to do this or has this feature been removed? Please make sure it applies to this rather new version of Skype for Android.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Skype, you need to follow these steps:

1. Go to the **Calls** tab.

   [image: CallsTAb]
2. Select the dial-pad icon
3. Type the number you want to send an SMS to.

   [image: SelectNumber]
4. Type your SMS and send.

   [image: TypeSMS]

Comment: The problem is my Skype app does not look like yours. Thanks for trying but that is not going to fly here. If anyone has a working solution for my version of the app (see my original screenshot) then please post an answer to this question.

Comment: Well, as you mentioned yours is latest version of skype. so, last I checked, the latest version is 8.24.0.2,which is my version as well and I have shared the screenshots of the same.what version are you using,if this is not what your Skype looks like.